# Finding x-intercept of absolute values

Tags: absolute-value

What is the x-intercept of $|x-12|+8$? I don't know how to solve it with the absolute values and whether there will be two answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have one, for if $|x - 12| + 8 = 0$, then $|x - 12| = -8 < 0$, which isn't possible.